# Error when install STS (Spring) in Eclipse Luna

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, git, maven

Step to reproduce:
1. Download Eclipse luna sr2 Packages from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/

2. Extra and open eclipse IDE
3. Click menu Help-> Eclipse Marketplace -> search 'Spring'  -> click 'Spring Tool Suite (STS) for Eclipse 3.7.7RELEASE'-> click 'Install'
4. After the Spring installation finished restart eclipse IDE
5. The git and maven are broken.

I copy some error fomr Error log:

1) FrameworkEvent ERROR in org.eclipse.egit.ui

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_NZ
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

org.eclipse.mylyn.git.ui
Error
Fri Mar 18 17:16:34 NZDT 2016
FrameworkEvent ERROR

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.mylyn.git.ui [269]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.egit.ui
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.egit.ui; bundle-version="4.2.0.201601211800-r"; singleton:="true"
       org.eclipse.egit.ui [458]
         No resolution report for the bundle.  Bundle was not resolved because of a uses contraint violation.
  org.osgi.service.resolver.ResolutionException: Uses constraint violation. Unable to resolve resource org.eclipse.egit.ui [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.egit.ui"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="4.2.0.201601211800-r"; singleton:="true"] because it is exposed to package 'com.jcraft.jsch' from resources com.jcraft.jsch [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.jcraft.jsch"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.1.53.v201508180515"] and com.jcraft.jsch [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.jcraft.jsch"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.1.51.v201410302000"] via two dependency chains.

Chain 1:
  org.eclipse.egit.ui [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.egit.ui"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="4.2.0.201601211800-r"; singleton:="true"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=com.jcraft.jsch)(&(bundle-version>=0.1.37)(!(bundle-version>=0.2.0))))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle: com.jcraft.jsch
  com.jcraft.jsch [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.jcraft.jsch"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.1.53.v201508180515"]

Chain 2:
  org.eclipse.egit.ui [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.egit.ui"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="4.2.0.201601211800-r"; singleton:="true"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=org.eclipse.jsch.core)(&(bundle-version>=1.1.100)(!(bundle-version>=2.0.0))))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle; osgi.wiring.bundle="org.eclipse.jsch.core"; bundle-version:Version="1.1.500.v20131112-1442"; singleton:="true"
  org.eclipse.jsch.core [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="org.eclipse.jsch.core"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="1.1.500.v20131112-1442"; singleton:="true"]
    require: (&(osgi.wiring.bundle=com.jcraft.jsch)(&(bundle-version>=0.1.50)(!(bundle-version>=1.0.0))))
     |
    provide: osgi.wiring.bundle: com.jcraft.jsch
  com.jcraft.jsch [osgi.identity; osgi.identity="com.jcraft.jsch"; type="osgi.bundle"; version:Version="0.1.51.v201410302000"]
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

2) FrameworkEvent ERROR

```
eclipse.buildId=4.4.2.M20150204-1700
java.version=1.7.0_51
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=linux, ARCH=x86_64, WS=gtk, NL=en_NZ
Framework arguments:  -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product
Command-line arguments:  -os linux -ws gtk -arch x86_64 -product org.eclipse.epp.package.java.product

org.eclipse.m2e.core
Error
Fri Mar 18 17:16:34 NZDT 2016
FrameworkEvent ERROR

org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.m2e.core [479]
  Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime; bundle-version="[1.7.0,1.8.0)"
    -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime; bundle-version="1.7.0.20160202-2118"; singleton:="false"
       org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime [491]
         Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple; bundle-version="[1.7.0,1.8.0)"
           -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple; bundle-version="1.7.0.20160202-2118"; singleton:="false"
              org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple [492]
                Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"

    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:434)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1582)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1561)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1533)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1476)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:340)
```

Answer (score 2):

I observed same type of issue with Maven plugin in eclipse when I copied my eclipse binary from one machine to another machine.

> org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: org.eclipse.m2e.core [479]
>     Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime; bundle-version="[1.7.0,1.8.0)"
>       -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime; bundle-version="1.7.0.20160202-2118"; singleton:="false"
>          org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime [491]
>            Unresolved requirement: Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple; bundle-version="[1.7.0,1.8.0)"
>              -> Bundle-SymbolicName: org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple; bundle-version="1.7.0.20160202-2118"; singleton:="false"
>                 org.eclipse.m2e.maven.runtime.slf4j.simple [492]
>                   **Unresolved requirement: Require-Capability: osgi.ee; filter:="(&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=1.8))"**

And the reason was the JDK7 on the new machine. When I pointed JDK8 in *eclipse.ini*, this issue get resolved.